# Is there a maven 2 archetype for spring 3 MVC applications?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, maven-2, maven-archetype

I'm experimenting with the spring 3 MVC framework. Since i use maven 2 to manage my project, i'm searching for a archetype to create a spring 3 MVC application.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [STS](http://www.springsource.org/sts) (spring tool suite) a new spring MVC template project creates a working application using spring 3.

Or you can using [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo/) to give a working foundation to your project.

Comment: Does STS create a maven project? I just installed STS and don't see any Spring MVC Project template available.

Comment: @AlexWorden STS creates a Maven project. In some cases, you can choose between Maven and Gradle

Answer (score 20):

I also couldn't find useful archetypes, so I have created my own. You can find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/spring-archetypes/). If you find anything you'd like to add, please don't hesitate to mail me or send a patch

Comment: here seems another one but for Spring + Vaadin this time. http://code.google.com/p/vaadin-spring-archetype/

Comment: Do you have one with Spring 4?

Answer (score 9):

[Spring MVC quickstart archetype](https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype) is available on GitHub, courtesy of [kolorobot](https://github.com/kolorobot). Good instructions are provided on how to install it to your local Maven repo and use it to create a new Spring MVC project. He’s even helpfully included the Tomcat 7 Maven plugin in the archetypical project so that the newly created Spring MVC can be run from the command line without having to manually deploy it to an application server.

Kolorobot’s example application includes the following:

- No-xml Spring MVC 3.2 web application for Servlet 3.0 environment
- Apache Tiles with configuration in place,
- Bootstrap
- JPA 2.0 (Hibernate/HSQLDB)
- JUnit/Mockito
- Spring Security 3.1

Answer (score 7):

[AppFuse](http://source.appfuse.org/changelog/appfuse/?cs=3327) and [AppFuse Light](http://source.appfuse.org/changelog/appfuse-light/?cs=214) have been upgraded to use Spring 3 so I *guess* you could use one of the appfuse [archetypes](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List).

But what is exactly a Spring MVC application if not a regular webapp with some dependencies on Spring 3 artefacts?

Comment: And now there is [SpringFuse](http://www.springfuse.com/) which povides usefull Spring archetypes.

Answer (score 3):

From the [springsource forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?110247-STS-mvc-archetype-%28-quot-Spring-MVC-Project-quot-archetype%29&p=365537#post365537):

In Spring Source Tool Suite.

Go to New -> Other -> Spring Source Tool Suite -> Spring Template Project -> Spring MVC Project

enter the details and click Finish.

Answer (score 1):

The Codehaus [Maven User Archetypes List](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List) has several archetypes including two from app-fuse that use Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1):

This archetype creates a Java web application that uses Spring MVC framework, Angular and Event Sourcing.

```
mvn archetype:generate \
 -DarchetypeGroupId=no.bouvet \
 -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-eventsourcing \
 -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.2 \
 -DgroupId=com.domain.myapp \
 -DartifactId=myapp
```

You can find the source here - [maven-archetype-eventsourcing](https://github.com/bouvet-openlab/maven-archetype-eventsourcing/)

And read the blogg - [Get your Event Sourced web application development started with one line using Maven!](http://blogg.bouvet.no/2014/07/08/get-your-event-sourced-web-application-development-started-with-one-line-using-maven/)

Answer (score 0):

A friend and I created this spring boiler plate for SPA applications. Could perhaps be useful to you https://github.com/PabloK/SpringRESTboilerplate

Answer (score 0):

What I do is create a new Spring Project and one of the selections available in STS Simple Spring Web Maven; it sets up a Spring 3 Maven webapp, just modify the pom to Spring 4 and do a clean install from the Run Config.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know it does not exist. But why didn't create your own?