# Maven 3 Archetype for Project With Spring, Spring MVC, Hibernate, JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jpa, archetypes

I'm trying to use Maven 3 to create a project which uses Spring 3, Spring MVC, Hibernate 4, and JPA.  However, when I execute:

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

Non of the archetypes listed include all of these; and even those which are close seem to be special projects such as projects with Flex.  I want to avoid having extra modules such as Flex that would crowd the project and configuration files.  So, is there an archetype for Maven 3 that I can use to create such a project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a maven 2 archetype for spring 3 MVC applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757269/is-there-a-maven-2-archetype-for-spring-3-mvc-applications)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Possible duplicate: [Is there a maven 2 archetype for spring 3 MVC applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757269/is-there-a-maven-2-archetype-for-spring-3-mvc-applications)

That said, I would encourage you to think about making your own archetype. The reason is, no matter what you end up getting from someone else's, you can do better in not that much time, and a decent sized Java project is going to end up making a lot of jar projects.

Answer (score 21):

A great [Spring MVC quickstart archetype](https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype) is available on GitHub, courtesy of [kolorobot](https://github.com/kolorobot). Good instructions are provided on how to install it to your local Maven repo and use it to create a new Spring MVC project. He’s even helpfully included the Tomcat 7 Maven plugin in the archetypical project so that the newly created Spring MVC can be run from the command line without having to manually deploy it to an application server.

Kolorobot’s example application includes the following:

- No-xml Spring MVC 3.2 web application for Servlet 3.0 environment
- Apache Tiles with configuration in place,
- Bootstrap
- JPA 2.0 (Hibernate/HSQLDB)
- JUnit/Mockito
- Spring Security 3.1

Comment: I should think the inclusion of thymeleaf, bootstrap, and mongodb in the configuration goes against the declaration that the OP wants to "avoid having extra modules".

Comment: Why should somebody use the spring mvc archetype in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://start.spring.io/ it basically gives you a kick starter with either maven or gradle build.

Note: This is a Spring Boot based archetype.

Answer (score 1):

With [appFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home) framework, you can create an Spring MVC archetype with jpa support, etc ...

Take a look at it's [quickStart guide](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart) to see how to create an archetype based on this Framework.

Foundational frameworks in AppFuse:

- Bootstrap and jQuery
- Maven, Hibernate, Spring and Spring Security
- Java 7, Annotations, JSP 2.1, Servlet 3.0
- Web Frameworks: JSF, Struts 2, Spring MVC, Tapestry 5, Wicket
- JPA Support

For example to create an appFuse light archetype :

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-light-struts-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=2.2.1 
-DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject
```