# Eliminating Spring.xml from Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring

In *Spring Framework* is it possible to eliminate the entire `Spring.xml` and use a configuration class with `@Configuration` and `@Bean` annotation for creating bean, and for all other purpose use a `spring.xml`?

Comment: Sure why not ... But why... It if works slowly migrate it to @Configuraition. Just use `@ImportResource` to import the original xml file and use it together with `@Configuration`.

Comment: Yup, this has been in spring for some time.  Here's a decent article http://www.robinhowlett.com/blog/2013/02/13/spring-app-migration-from-xml-to-java-based-config/

Comment: refer to answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594303/maven-3-archetype-for-project-with-spring-spring-mvc-hibernate-jpa/18049397#18049397

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have pure java configuration in Spring. You have to create a class and annotate it with `@Configuration`. We annotate methods with `@Bean` and instantiate the Spring bean and return it from that method.

```
@Configuration
public class SomeClass {

     @Bean
     public SomeBean someBean() {
         return new SomeBean();
     }
}
```

If you want to enable component scanning, then you can give `@ComponentScan(basePackages="specify_your_package")` under the `@Configuration`. Also the method name as someBean serves as bean id. Also if you have to inject a dependency, you can use constructor injection and do as following:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeClass {

     @Bean
     public SomeDependency someDependency() {
         return new SomeDependency();
     }

     @Bean
     public SomeBean someBean() {
         return new SomeBean(someDependency());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,most of (maybe all of)[official guides](https://spring.io/guides) uses absolutely no xml configuration file,just annotations.