# Pre-Configured Java Web Application Project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, java-package

*Everytime when I create a new java web project, I have to configure and add many folders and property files for primefaces, hibernate, jsf, ldap, tomcat etc.*

It wastes all my time. I find a solution for this, but it is not a generic solution.

My solution is that, I created a web project and configure all props and folders but not develop any code. It was an configured empty project. I mean it was my custom template project.

When I want to create a new web project, I always have to import this configured project and rename it. It's not a good way I think.

*So, In the project creation tab, how can I add my custom project to creation wizard or how can I create my custom project in the beginning.*

- **Is there any plugin or tool to create pre-configured template web project ?**
- **Is there any tutorial to develop an eclipse plugin to do this ?**

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: are you using spring?

Comment: what about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757269/is-there-a-maven-2-archetype-for-spring-3-mvc-applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need e.g. `maven archetype` that would generate such a project.

Alternatively you can use [Spring Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.org/sts), it has some predefined templates.

If you want to create plugin by yourself you can read more about [Creating Eclipse Wizards (by Lars Vogel)](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWizards/article.html). But this is not so trivial (may need some work to make it work perfectly). Generally whole Lars Vogel's site is about creating Eclipse plugins.

Comment: STS predefined templates are unsufficient for my projects.

Comment: So if you have really custom ones, you can create either your own archetype and use Eclipse to create new project based on archetype, or as you said write Eclipse Plugin. Vogella is the site where you find all the stuff you need to start programming in Eclipse RCP.