# Maven Archetype for Spring 4 + Hibernate 4 Web Application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I want to create a **Web application** using Maven that involves technologies Spring 4 + Hibernate 4.

Without using STS, if we want to create is there any Archetype available ?

**"mvn archetype:generate"** this command shows a list of templates available , but i couldn't find the combination **Spring Web MVC + Hibernate**.

***kolorobot***'s template doesn't have proper packages for source code (controllers,services,DAOs,Entities have to be in respective packages).

Answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757269/is-there-a-maven-2-archetype-for-spring-3-mvc-applications) suggest to use STS which i don't want to try now.

Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try http://start.spring.io ... Select web, select hibernate... Generate project.

Comment: thanks @M.Deinum I downloaded the demo.zip and it doesn't have any hibernate / spring related classes .. do i need to run some command after extracting the zip. Am using http://start.spring.io/ for the first time

Comment: Why would you need classes... It will generate the pom and a bootstrap class ... Add your entities yourself...

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry, I am new to Spring, I don't know what is Spring Boot, what it's simplifying for a developer.